# Is there a way to create a random vnumber following some general distribution

Tags: java, random

I've been stuck with this problem and I don't know what to do. Suppose a general function of distribution f(x). For simplicity let us suppose that integral of f(x) is 1 in the range of our random numbers

How does one create a function that would return a random number, such that distribution of those random numbers over numberline would be f(x)?

My attempt:

Create two random numbers with no distribution between 0 and 1:  a and b

If f(a)<b then return a, else go recursive.

The problem is that 0<=b<=1, but f(a) can have any value from 0 up to infinity, so there would points, where point would get for sure

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling for one of the most common approaches. By the way, the integral of f(x) ***must be*** 1 or else it's not a probability density function.

Comment: Please note that there's not a one-size-fits-all solution to your question. [Here's a link](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html) to a text book (more than 800 pages) containing theory and algorithms spanning this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem of sampling from probability distributions is well-studied, and a number of techniques are available based on the specific case.  Generally, something about the function must be known: a samplable distribution which has a constant multiple that bounds the target distribution, its integral/CDF, for example.  [Wikipedia has a list of options.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_random_variate_generation?wprov=sfla1)